# Modal Box not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm trying to make a modal box on a website, but it's not showing up.The content in the modal box is fine, but here I also attach the content's CSS code if maybe needed.

```js
document.getElementById('buttonL').addEventListener("click", function() {
document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
});

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click", function() {
document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
.bg-modal{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
display: none;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
bottom: 0px;
}

.modal-content{
width: 600px;
height: 300px;
background-color: white;
opacity: 1;
border-radius: 2px;
}

.modal-content h1{
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 40px;
font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

.modal-content img{
float: left;
width: 160px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 60px;
}

.modal-content p{
float: right;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 60px;
font-size: 16px;
}


.close {
position: relative;
float: right;
margin-right: 8px;
font-size: 32px;
color: #333;
background-color: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="buttonL" class="buttonLegal">LEGAL DETAILS</button>
<div class="bg-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close">✖</div>
        <h1>LEGAL DETAILS</h1>
        <img src="someimagehere.jpg">
        <p>some text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've searched the whole internet and tried many ways but still failed to show the modal box. I think I may have a mistake in my Javascript code but I'm not sure. So, I hope you can help me in this matter. Thank you!

Comment: [your code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/r2baspjh/)

Comment: Its working fine

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-not-showing?file=index.js

Comment: You might be having any console error before the execution of this code.

Comment: I have added your code in snippet view without changing anything and it's working fine

Comment: @nickbullock Thank you! I just copied the whole of my website code to stackblitz and it's working fine. But when I try it using LiveServer, it's still not working. Also I already enabled Javascript in Chrome, still don't know where did I do it wrong..

Comment: @SuperUser Thank you! But when I try it using LiveServer, it's still not working. Also I already enabled Javascript in Chrome, still don't know where did I do it wrong..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple modal code from https://www.w3schools.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```